# Hostapd Failed to update rate sets in kernel module

Tags: wireless, kernel, wireless-access-point, hostapd

I'm getting this error launching hostapd with minimal conf

```
Failed to update rate sets in kernel module
```

I've just installed Ubuntu-GNOME 13.04. When I was using Ubuntu 12.04 did not receive this kind of error, so I assume is not hardware problem.
Do I need to add extra wifi drivers? How to?

Kernel info:

```
Linux  3.8.0-31-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 10 19:56:49 UTC 2013 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux
```

PC: Aspire One 722.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it shows this message it seems to be working for me...

```
sudo hostapd thirdParty/hostapd-test.conf 
Configuration file: thirdParty/hostapd-test.conf
Failed to update rate sets in kernel module
Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr 00:25:d3:64:49:35 and ssid 'test'
wlan0: STA f8:0c:f3:5e:a1:14 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
wlan0: STA f8:0c:f3:5e:a1:14 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
wlan0: AP-STA-CONNECTED f8:0c:f3:5e:a1:14
wlan0: STA f8:0c:f3:5e:a1:14 RADIUS: starting accounting session 529118DC-00000000
```

and worked for me with this tuto: [Here](http://nims11.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/hostapd-the-linux-way-to-create-virtual-wifi-access-point/)